# Is it possible to hide the point "edge" in Gadfly?

Tags: julia, gadfly

In Matlab, points have a `MarkerEdgeColor` that can be set to `"None"` (or any other color).
In Julia, using Gadfly, points (`Geom.point`) in discrete color space have a white edge and points in continuous color space have a dark highlighted edge. I want to suppress that, so there is no "edge".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching on google found this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/GiovineItalia/Gadfly.jl/issues/618). But the solutions suggested there `Theme(discrete_highlight_color=c->nothing)` did not work for me.

Looking at the code for [Geom.Point](https://github.com/GiovineItalia/Gadfly.jl/blob/2cbd6d4ccd47125b2db8cb02f8a7e798c51c5bcc/src/geom/point.jl), I found that line 80 referred to a `theme.highlight_width`. Setting this to 0 worked for me.

```
using Gadfly
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame(x = randn(100), y=randn(100), c=rand(100))
plot(df, x=:x,y=:y,color=:c, Geom.point)
t = Theme(highlight_width=0)
plot(df, x=:x,y=:y,color=:c, Geom.point,t)
```